# Android build error, eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Any idea why I am getting this error message while building an Android project in Eclipse Kepler? Was able to build this till last evening. Suddenly it stops from this morning. Seems weird.

```
The library 'native-libs.jar' contains native libraries that will not run on the device.
Additionally some of those libraries will interfer with the installation of the application because of their location in lib/
lib/ is reserved for NDK libraries.
The following libraries were found:
  - lib/armeabi/libpclnetwork.so
  - lib/armeabi/libtlvtree.so
  - lib/armeabi/libpclapi.so
  - lib/armeabi/libpcltools.so
```

**Additional info:**

Android SDK 24.0.2

ADT Plugin 23.0.4.1468518

Project was build using Google API level 19

Comment: `because of their location in lib/`: put your **jar** files in the `/libs/` folder (mind the **s**).

Comment: I don't even have the lib folder. It is already libs.

Comment: Maybe, some referred projects or libraries addressing the offending path?

Comment: I just deleted the project and imported again. And it is working now. But if you ask me about the reason for the issue then no idea. Let me keep the ticket open for a day, some body else may have a better idea and explanation.

Comment: Maybe, it had an old project version in its cache.